# When PHP runs a module, Apache cannot start

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php

Yesterday, I was enjoying just messing around with the website code, since I've not touched the actual settings of PHP and Apache since yesterday...
(I must say I had the module php_mysql enabled)
I made a MySQL connector yesterday and worked perfectly!
This morning, I start up the computer and when I try to run Apache, it gives me 'The requested operation has failed'.
I look in the apache log and I see this.

```
[Fri Feb 22 08:07:39 2013] [warn] pid file C:/dev/progs/Apache/Apache2/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

I looked around the internet and found I must delete that file. I tried deleting then restarting but that didn't work.

Then I found that disabling all PHP modules will work. So I went ahead and disabled the php_mysql module (that is the only one enabled).

Then it starts up again!
Except I want it to start with MySQL. Then I try to run the connector on my php page. I get this.

```
[22-Feb-2013 07:59:54] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\dev\www\test\index.php on line 48
```

So I really want mysql to run on PHP, but I don't want mysql to stop me running Apache...

Any help?

(Running Apache/2.0.64 PHP/5.2.17 MySQL5.6 - Win32 Home Premium)

Comment: Your dependencies are broken.

Comment: Dependencies? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

The first message is just a warning, you should always use `apachectl` to start/stop/restart apache. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/apachectl.html

The most common cause of PHP not starting but working fine when the extensions are disabled is due to an incorrect extension path or missing file. You will need to set this in php.ini, then restart apache (using apachectl of course). More than likely the extension_dir in php.ini is not pointing to your dll files, by default it points to `./` from memory.

Instructions on windows extensions from php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php